# Calculating average leads created per month, across stores

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to calculate the average amount of leads (rows) created per month, across stores.

**Schema and Input:**

```
CREATE TABLE leads
    (`id` int, `store_id` int, `created_at` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO leads
    (`id`, `store_id`, `created_at`)
VALUES
    (5211, 1, '2019-09-13 23:29:29'),
    (5212, 1, '2019-08-13 21:29:29'),
    (5781, 1, '2019-08-16 21:29:29'),
    (3349, 5, '2019-10-16 23:29:29'),
    (3344, 5, '2019-10-16 23:29:29'),
    (6291, 8, '2019-08-14 21:29:29'),
    (6292, 8, '2019-08-14 22:29:29'),
    (6299, 8, '2019-08-14 11:29:29'),
    (7799, 8, '2019-10-16 23:29:29'),
    (9898, 8, '2019-08-13 23:29:29'),
    (7791, 8, '2019-10-16 23:29:29'),
    (7792, 8, '2019-10-16 23:29:29'),
    (7793, 8, '2019-10-16 23:29:29'),
    (7794, 8, '2019-10-16 23:29:29'),
    (7795, 8, '2019-10-16 23:29:29')
;
```

**Desired Output:**

```
average_leads_per_month_per_store, month_name
3, 2018-08
1, 2018-09
4, 2018-10
```

**What I have tried:**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS leads_count, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") month_name, store_id, created_at
FROM leads
GROUP BY month_name, store_id
ORDER BY month_name, store_id;

| leads_count | month_name | store_id |           created_at |
|-------------|------------|----------|----------------------|
|           2 |    2019-08 |        1 | 2019-08-13T21:29:29Z |
|           4 |    2019-08 |        8 | 2019-08-14T21:29:29Z |
|           1 |    2019-09 |        1 | 2019-09-13T23:29:29Z |
|           2 |    2019-10 |        5 | 2019-10-16T23:29:29Z |
|           6 |    2019-10 |        8 | 2019-10-16T23:29:29Z |
```

This groups by year-month and store, now I need to calculate the average for each month across stores.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/034661/14

Comment: What if a store does not have a lead in a particular month?  Is it ignored or counted as `0`?

Comment: It should be counted @GordonLinoff.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this will give you the average

```
SELECT COUNT(id)*1.0/(1.0*count(distinct store_id)) AS leads_count, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") month_name
FROM leads T
GROUP BY month_name
ORDER BY month_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your result,

At `2019-08` month, you have `2 + 4 leads_count` per `1 & 8` store_id, As a result, you have `(6/2 = 3)`

At `2019-09` month, you have `1 leads_count` per `1` store_id, As a result, you have `(1/1 = 1)`

At `2019-10` month, you have `2 + 6 leads_count` per `5 & 8` store_id, As a result, you have `(8 / 2 = 4)`

As a result, you need to count `leads_count` then division Total of `store_id`.

You can achieve it in this way

```
SELECT COUNT(id) / Count(Distinct (store_id)) AS average_leads_per_month_per_store, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") month_name
FROM leads T
GROUP BY month_name
ORDER BY month_name;
```

Live demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/034661/46).

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Andrew.Maston

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The simplest syntax in MySQL would seem to be:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') as month_name,
       COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT store_id) as avg_per_month
FROM leads T
GROUP BY month_name
ORDER BY month_name;
```

EDIT:

If you need to count stores with *no* leads, then you need some source of all stores.  Presumably, you have a `stores` table:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(l.created_at, '%Y-%m') as month_name,
       COUNT(*) / s.num_stores as avg_per_month
FROM leads l. CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_stores FROM stores) s
GROUP BY l.month_name, s.num_stores
ORDER BY month_name;
```